# How to highlight and detect mouse clicks on a css grid row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, highlight

I'm trying to create a menu which I'm laying out using CSS grid.  The problem that I'm having is figuring out how I can make the menu interactive when the mouse is hovering over each menu item.

I would like to be able to highlight the entire row when the mouse is over any of the menu items in the row.  I can highlight each individual grid cell by adding a :hover css rule, but I don't know how to highlight the entire grid row.

The second part is then detecting when a row is being clicked. Again, I can add an onClick event handler to each cell but that doesn't seem ideal, as users could accidentally click in the gap between grid cells.  I was thinking that if I can figure out how to highlight the entire row, then i could add the click handler to this row highlighter and that would solve the gap click problem.

I have created a codepen example that demonstrates how the menu is currently constructed: https://codepen.io/marekKnows_com/pen/RqMgGw

HTML:

```
<div class="myGrid">
  <div class="anchor" id="item1">
    <i class="image material-icons">folder_open</i>
  </div>
  <span class="text">Open...</span>
  <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+O</span>

  <div class="anchor" id="item2">
    <i class="image material-icons">save</i>
  </div>
  <span class="text">Save...</span>
  <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+S</span>

  <div class="anchor" id="item3"></div>
  <span class="text">Action</span>

  <div class="separator"></div>

  <div class="anchor" id="item4"></div>
  <span class="text">Exit</span>
  <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+X</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myGrid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto auto;
  grid-gap: 2px 6px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: start;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.image { 
  width: 24px;
}
.text {
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px
}
.shortcut {
  justify-self: end;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px
}
.separator {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Easier and faster with flex and changed structure, also more appropriate.

Comment: just add #item1:hover > .mygrid{ border:1px solid red }

Comment: I can't use flex because that doesn't guarantee that all the images, text and shortcuts will line up in nice columns.  That is why I went with a grid and not a flex layout.

Comment: #item1:hover > .mygrid{ border:1px solid red } doesn't work.  I pasted into my codepen example and I don't see anything happen

Answer (score 3):

One option is to wrap the row elements with a div, include style `display: contents;` in the wrapper div, add the click handler to the wrapper div.

CSS grid will treat the elements inside the wrapper as if there was no wrapper when laying out the contents, so they will be aligned as you desire. See [MDN display-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-box) for more info. That link also points out browsers have accessibility bugs with `display: contents;`.

`display: contents;` does not allow styling though. To highlight the entire grid row you will need to use other CSS techniques. This wrapper div could be used in your CSS selector.

I have tested only with Firefox so far.

```
<div class="myGrid">

  <div class="row" onclick="console.log('click');">
    <div class="anchor" id="item1">
      <i class="image material-icons">folder_open</i>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Open...</span>
    <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+O</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row" onclick="console.log('click');">
    <div class="anchor" id="item2">
      <i class="image material-icons">save</i>
    </div>
    <span class="text">Save...</span>
    <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+S</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row" onclick="console.log('click');">
    <div class="anchor" id="item3"></div>
    <span class="text">Action</span>
  </div>

  <div class="separator"></div>

  <div class="row" onclick="console.log('click');">
    <div class="anchor" id="item4"></div>
    <span class="text">Exit</span>
    <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+X</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
.myGrid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto auto;
  grid-gap: 2px 6px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: start;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: contents;
}
.image { 
  width: 24px;
}
.text {
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px
}
.shortcut {
  justify-self: end;
  padding: 0 5px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px
}
.separator {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work.  What I ended up doing was making the anchor element have position relative.  Then I added a new div with position absolute under the anchor element.  From within JavaScript I can size the new element to be the full width of the grid and using z-index I can position it relative to the other elements in the row accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```
       .anchor:hover > 
       .mygrid
       { background:red }
```

> check this if it works on hovering item1 it will change the border color(from black to red as highlighting)

Comment: #item1:hover > .mygrid{ border:1px solid red } doesn't work. I pasted into my codepen example and I don't see anything happen, could you post a working codepen example with your suggested change. Maybe I'm missing a detail

Comment: did you hover on item1

Comment: Yes, see here.  Hovering over any of the items doesn't display anything in red.  https://codepen.io/marekKnows_com/pen/rQdGOM

Comment: i have replaced something. Actually i am trying on mob so cant see the hover effect. Can you please try to add this css style which ive again written above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184109/discussion-between-marekknows-com-and-himanshu-ahuja).

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you might want to change your html so the `.anchor` elements are wrapping each item.

```
<div class="myGrid">
    <div class="anchor" id="item1">
        <i class="image material-icons">folder_open</i>
        <span class="text">Open...</span>
        <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+O</span>
    </div>
    <div class="anchor" id="item2">
        <i class="image material-icons">save</i>
        <span class="text">Save...</span>
        <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+S</span>
    </div>
    <div class="anchor" id="item3">
        <span class="text">Action</span>
    </div>
    <div class="separator"></div>
    <div class="anchor" id="item4">
        <span class="text">Exit</span>
        <span class="shortcut">Ctrl+X</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then use flex to align the contents of each item

```
.myGrid {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.anchor {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

/* Hover for each anchor */
.anchor:hover {
    background: red;
}

.image { 
    width: 24px;
}

.text {
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px
}

.shortcut {
    margin-left: auto; /* push the shortcut to the right */
    padding: 0 5px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px
}

.separator {
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQWLaE

Comment: Can't use a flex layout because it doesn't guarantee that all the images, text and shortcuts will line up in nice columns. That is why i'm using a grid instead.  Note in your example, Action and Exit are not properly aligned anymore.